# Creating a monotone matrix from a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given a matrix $\mathbf{X}$, is there a method to derive a monotone matrix from $\mathbf{X}$, which is somehow related to $\mathbf{X}$ ?

Comment: How do you define a monotone matrix ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_matrix

Comment: You will have to be a little bit more specific about what you are looking for. The matrix $Y = (\|X\|_2+1) I$ is a monotone matrix derived from $X$ and it is "somehow" related to $X$ since $\|Y\|_2 = \|X\|_2+1$.

Comment: @CarlChristian.  In fact, I am looking for such relations.  Is there a general rule for getting monotone matrices, for example a PSD can be obtained by finding the gram matrix of the given matrix. As I can see, 1+Frobenius norm times identity matrix seems to be monotone.  Is there a general statement in general for norms and generalizing the identity matrix ?